# How to use VueJS data key with space

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am working with existed Database which every table columns are containing white space. As result as VueJS api, I got the data key with white-space as below:

```
data = {
Course Trained:"82",
Course trained 2:null,
Delivery Channel:"IA2DC1",
End Date:"2017-05-06",
Full Name:"9",
ID:"1",
Intervention:"IA2",
Number of sessions:"5",
Start Date:"2017-05-02",
Training Orginisation:"2",
}
```

My problem is when I tried to use **'v-model' => 'Course Trained'**, the whole page compiled an error.

How can I deal with this with-space in VueJS?

PS. I cannot remove space to change the table column name. because it linked to many relationship and 3rd party application.

Comment: yes, the whitespace of the key is my issue. Example, I want to access to key name: **Course Trained** via **v-model**. the whole page will compile error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea using data variable with spaces. It will make you life complicated.

But anyway, you can access/v-model it using `yourdata[key_name]` like below:

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    test: { //if not root
      'test name': "Cat in Boots"
    },
    'test 1': 'Snow White' // if root
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>{{test['test name']}}</h2>
    <input v-model="test['test name']">
    <h2>{{$data['test 1']}}</h2>
    <input v-model="$data['test 1']">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

As the author of Vue said: **this** will be changed in the compiled template depending on the function scope you are in.

So don't use **this** in the template, especially `v-model`.

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    'test 1': 'Cat in Boots'
  }
})
```

```css
a {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>{{this['test 1']}}</h2>
    <input v-model="this['test 1']"> <a>If using `this`, you will find v-model not working as expected</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, +1, and if `'test name'` is in the root, the OP could use `<input v-model="$data['test name']">` as well (though it is much better to nest it in a property like you do in this demo).

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, updated my answer. Actually I am trying v-model="this['test name']", but it will cause the data can't get the update. I am googling it, but no helpfull information is found.. do you know what is the difference `$data['test 1']` and `this['test 1']`. Maybe have to look into vue source code to see how to implement v-model.

Comment: what I thought is we can access data in method or computed like `this.test`, that is why my first thought is using `this['test']`. If change `<h2>{{$data['test 1']}}</h2>` to `<input v-model="this['test 1']">`, it seems work, but actually if change the value of input, it will not get the update. it seems the input bind one value which is one clone from `$data['test 1']`

Comment: Thanks so much. my problem is solved. both ``$data['test 1']`` and ``this['test 1']`` are working for me.

Comment: @LimSocheat check this [don't use **this** in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008446/what-are-the-differences-between-thiskey-and-datakey-for-v-model/50010533#50010533)

Comment: @Sphinx, thanks so much for information, I will use ``$data`` instead then.

Answer (score 1):

Use allias with Laravel Eloquent query for column which have space, so you donot have to bother in the front end code,

Also having space in column, is really a poor database design and you will end up very complicated issues..

Comment: Thanks so much, that can be the optional way to do because there are thousand of table columns which I cannot keep aliasing every columns. Because I am working on existed database that designed by someone else, so I cannot make any change to columns name.