# what are the differences between this['key'] and $data['key'] for v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please look into below snippet, there are three demos, first two demos are working fine (v-model working fine).

But for the last one, when you type in something in the `<input>`, you will see `this['test 1']` will not be updated. `<h2>Name:<span>{{this['test 1']}}</span></h2>` always is the intial value.

It seems `v-model` bind one clone for `this['test 1']`. We have to use `$data['test 1']` for this situation.

Does anyone know what caused the differences?

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
    'test': "Cat in Boots",
    'test 1': 'Snow White'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testCase1: function(){
      this['test'] = 'I am Cat in Boots' //works
      this['test 1'] = 'I am Cat in Boots' //works
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span {
  background-color:green
}

a {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="testCase1()">Test Case 1</button>It will change the data successfully.
    <h2>Name:<span>{{test}}</span></h2>
    <input v-model="test">
    <h2>Name:<span>{{$data['test 1']}}</span></h2>
    <input v-model="$data['test 1']">
    <h2>Name:<span>{{this['test 1']}}</span></h2>
    <input v-model="this['test 1']"><a>Type something in this input, the name will not be changed.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Very strange behavior, indeed. That's why you shouldn't access the component's data like you'd access an array

Comment: @Phiter normally we will not use one string with space as one key of one component data. So we will not meet above situation. I am just curious what causes this.

Comment: It looks like you end up referring to a different object with `this`.  Check to make sure you're not actually editing some global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `this` in the template as it doesn't refer to the component in the template, so using `$data` is necessary in that case

Answer (score 0):

**The root cause is**:

As the author of Vue said: **this** will be changed in the compiled template depending on the function scope you are in.

So **don't** use **this** in the template.

Check the feedback from Vue authorhttps://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8080

Also you can check the source codes for directive->model.js at [github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/compiler/directives/model.js).